# how to call a function on [browser tab close,browser close,backforward,refresh]

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

i need to code for browser in js/jQuery to execute/call a function on browser close, on browser tab close, back, forward, refresh.

Comment: Research the `onbeforeunload` event. Note however, that this will fire for *all* of the actions you describe. You cannot know specifically which has occured (ie. if the user refreshed or closed the tab)

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'are you sure?';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

support

```
Feature         Chrome  Edge    Firefox (Gecko) IE  Opera   Safari
Basic support   1.0     (Yes)   1               4   12      3
```

Comment: its show in popup, with default message i need not to show message i need to do something in background.and then that action need to perform what ever user did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.load`, `window.onunload` and for back and forward use `browser history`.

you can find more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API